# Porqué no me funciona la recursion en Kotlin usando collections?

Tags: kotlin

estoy tratando de resolver un ejercicio en Kotlin usando recursión y colecciones (mutablesetOf y mutableListOf) pero no puedo entender o no he encontrado algo que me explique porque no me esta funcionando el código, el caso es que si uso un forEach o incluso un for tradicional si me funciona, pero no usando la recursión.

Este ejercicio busca resolver el problema 055 de codeabbey: recibiremos una cadena como esta **nun lam mip tex bal pif sot bal bod tex end**
y devolveremos solo una vez los elementos repetidos es decir algo asi:
**bal tex**

Este seria el ejercicio usando recursión:

```
fun main() {
    var text = readLine()!!
    var splitText = text.split(' ')
    val size = splitText.size
    matchingWords(splitText, size, 0)
}

fun matchingWords(splitText: List<String>, size: Int, i: Int) {
    val set = mutableSetOf<String>()
    val duplicados = mutableListOf<String>()

    if (i != size){
        val word = splitText.elementAt(i)
        if (!set.add(word))
            if (!duplicados.contains(word))
                duplicados.add(word)
        matchingWords(splitText, size, i+ 1)
    }
    println(duplicados)
}
```

y este seria usando ciclos y metodos de recorrer collections

```
fun main() {
  var text = readLine()!!
  var splitText = text.split(' ')
  matchingWords(splitText)
}

fun matchingWords(splitText: List<String>) {
  val set = mutableSetOf<String>()
  val duplicates = mutableListOf<String>()

  splitText.forEach {
    if (!set.add(it)) {
      if (!duplicates.contains(it)) {
        duplicates.add(it)
      }
    }
    
  }
  print(duplicates.sorted().toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
  .replace(",", ""))
}
```

Comment: En cada llamada a la función `matchingWords` un nuevo `set` es creado y por lo tanto estará vacío, con lo cual nunca encontrará duplicados. Por cierto, puedes usar la función `joinToString` para concatenar elementos de una lista, especificando opcionalmente un separador, un prefijo y un sufijo; así no tienes que llamar a `replace` tantas veces.

Comment: Excelente respuesta amigo, ya se que debo buscar otra forma de resolver esto y tambien gracias por la sugerencia del joinToString